# How to separate the linked auto rig pro between our two characters?

Tags: rigging, auto-rig-pro

I finish the number 1 character with auto rigging, and bind it, then I add another auto rigging for the number 2 character but there is a problem, when I bind it, number 2's rig became the number 1's rig, and now it is all linked.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl9G7.png)

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Autorig Pro, but I reckon there is a way somewhere to force it creating a new rig rather than re-generating the already existing one.

If you were using Rigify, it would be as simple as removing the "target rig" next to the Generate button. Maybe the Autorig Pro equivalent is this :

[image]

---

Alternatively, or in fact more importantly, no matter the situation :
**You should not rig multiple characters in the same file.**

In professional productions, no company ever creates multiple assets in the same file unless there is a very specific need for it.
Assets are each in their own file which can be easily linked/referenced in the animation scenes, you can easily make asset versions and updates, and that avoid this kind of issue altogether.